# $x\mapsto f(x^{1/p})$ is smooth if and only if $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ whenever $p\nmid n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This is a slight generalization of something I got stuck on when trying to do Problem 2-5 from *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* by John M. Lee (which uses the case $p=3$).

> Let $p\ge 1$ be an integer, let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function, and define $g(x)=f(x^{1/p})$. Then $g$ is smooth if and only if $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ whenever $n$ is not divisible by $p$ and $n\ge 1$.

(Here *smooth* means that $f^{(n)}$ exists on $\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\ge 0$.)

This is obvious if $f$ is analytic. But I'm not sure whether this is true for general smooth $f$.

Comment: I don't know if this is true, but my gut says no. What's to stop us from creating a function which vanishes correctly, but whose order of vanishing isn't enough?

Comment: @AlexYoucis: I think it's true, because Lee essentially asks the reader to prove this result for $p=3$ in one of the problems. Well, after some reduction anyway. I don't know what you mean by "order of vanishing".

Comment: Maybe it's naïveté, but it seems like the operative thing is that the vanishing of $f$'s derivatives should counteract the singularity of $x^{\frac{1}{p}}$--but why does the amount $f$ vanishes (i.e. $x^2\sin(x)$ has order of vanishing $3$ at $0$) necessarily cancel out the singularity?